# Why does Unity look transparent?

Tags: atmosphere, visibility-of-spacecraft, optical, virgin-galactic

The BBC's [Virgin Galactic: Sir Richard Branson rockets to the edge of space](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-57797297) includes the image below.

Much of the Unity spacecraft appears (almost) transparent in this image; you can see the blue sky right through it. Why?

[image: Unity soars into the New Mexico sky (Virgin Galactic via BBC)]

> Unity soars into the New Mexico sky (Virgin Galactic via BBC)

Here at apogee the spacecraft now looks white:

[image: Screen shot from embedded video in the BBC article. Caption: the moment Sir Richard Branson's rocket plane reached its highest altitude]

Screen shot from embedded video in the BBC article.

> The moment Sir Richard Branson's rocket plane reached its highest altitude

Comment: It's *shiny*. Very, very *shiny*.

Comment: It doesn't look "transparent"; Wonder Woman isn't involved. It looks *blue*.

Comment: @RussellBorogove okay let's do some word mincing. When I look out my window at the sky during the day, I often see blue light. But I do not say "the glass looks blue" because my brain understands what "transparent" is. In this case large areas of the spacecraft have the same color as the sky in the rest of the image. That's just what would happen for transparent airplanes as you point out. Let's look to a good answer post to sort this all out.

Comment: An engineer, a physicist, and a mathematician are driving through the Scottish highlands in the winter, and passed a flock of sheep in a snowfield. The engineer looked out of the window and said "Look! Scottish sheep are white!"
The physicist said, "No, no. Some Scottish sheep are white."
The mathematician looked irritated. "There is at least one Scottish field, containing at least one sheep, which is transparent."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Much of the Unity spacecraft appears (almost) transparent in this image; you can see the blue sky right through it.

This is absolute nonsense; you cannot see the sky through Unity's airframe. It is opaque.

The upper surface of Unity is indeed painted mainly white.

The underside appears to be painted in a dark blue and black iris-and-pupil design, providing contrast for the "Virgin" logo in white.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand the nature of your question. Can we stipulate that, 1, the vehicle is not transparent, and 2, a number of optical effects and image processing techniques can cause the apparent colors of objects to vary under different viewing conditions, and 3, stipulation 2 is generally irrelevant to space exploration?

Comment: SE questions provide a place for (hopefully good) answers to be posted. Yours looks *great!*

Comment: [How much blue sky comes from each altitude; dependence of atmosphere's dielectric constant and isothermal compressibility with altitude?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650898/83380)

Answer (score 3):

Oh my, so much downvoting just for naivete! What this question is about is called [aerial perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_perspective). It's commonly seen with mountains, because they can be quite far from the observer:

[image]
([image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MonNatForest.jpg))

Of course, the mountains don't become more transparent the farther they are, they are just behind a thick layer of air that scatters sunlight into the observer and thus masks the objects behind it.

In fact, this is the same effect that makes lunar maria look blue instead of their normally gray/brown color:

[image]
(image source: [a post by Dan Finnerty at DPReview](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2420823))

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Yes, sometimes my titles sound naive: [Is the ISS a tennis racket?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1428/12102) :-) In pursuit of something quantitative I'd also asked (naively) in Physics SE: [How much blue sky comes from each altitude; dependence of atmosphere's dielectric constant and isothermal compressibility with altitude?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650898/83380)

Comment: It's not naivite, it is deliberate provocation. Likely well-intended, but unwise. When is someone that deliberately posts a known false controversial statement a Troll, and when is the same person an Admin, trying to seed some critical thinking and debate?